# Error While Reading Large Excel Files (xlsx) Via Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, out-of-memory, xlsx

I am trying to read large excel files xlsx via Apache POI, say 40-50 MB. I am getting out of memory exception. The current heap memory is 3GB.

I can read smaller excel files without any issues. I need a way to read large excel files and then them back as response via Spring excel view.

```
public class FetchExcel extends AbstractView {


    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(
            Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws Exception {

    String fileName = "SomeExcel.xlsx";

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open("/someDir/SomeExcel.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);

    ServletOutputStream respOut = response.getOutputStream();

    pkg.close();
    workbook.write(respOut);
    respOut.flush();

    workbook = null;                    

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +fileName+ "\"");


    }    

}
```

I first started off using `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream in);`
but that was costly per Apache POI API, so I switched to OPC package way but still the same effect. I don't need to parse  or process the file, just read it and return it.

Comment: Try SXSSF http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: I need an example. I search the web but can't find an example for reading large sheets via SXSSF, otherwise wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @jamesT did you run this option? -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M

Comment: Nevermind, SXSSF is intended to write large amounts of data only. Give JVM heap more memory and avoid such rude comments.

Comment: Have you tried a ODBC connection? Maybe will be a better approach

Comment: Did you write to local file, may be problem is about web application.

Comment: It's reading from a directory which has xlsx files.

Comment: Did you try looking at the [POI XSSF event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) which provides very low memory read support?

Comment: Similar Large Excel XLSX file reading discussion on post http://stackoverflow.com/a/13480820/1343356, Have a look!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't mention whether you need to modify the spreadsheet or not.

This may be obvious, but if you don't need to modify the spreadsheet, then you don't need to parse it and write it back out, you can simply read bytes from the file, and write out bytes, as you would with, say an image, or any other binary format.

If you do need to modify the spreadsheet before sending it to the user, then to my knowledge, you may have to take a different approach.

Every library that I'm aware of for reading Excel files in Java reads the whole spreadsheet into memory, so you'd have to have 50MB of memory available for every spreadsheet that could possibly be concurrently processed. This involves, as others have pointed out, adjusting the heap available to the VM.

If you need to process a large number of spreadsheets concurrently, and can't allocate enough memory, consider using a format that can be streamed, instead of read all at once into memory. CSV format can be opened by Excel, and I've had good results in the past by setting the content-type to application/vnd.ms-excel, setting the attachment filename to something ending in ".xls", but actually returning CSV content. I haven't tried this in a couple of years, so YMMV.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example to read a large xls file using sax parser.

```
public void parseExcel(File file) throws IOException {

        OPCPackage container;
        try {
            container = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutePath());
            ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(container);
            XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(container);
            StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
            XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                InputStream stream = iter.next();

                processSheet(styles, strings, stream);
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OpenXML4JException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

protected void processSheet(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream) throws IOException, SAXException {

        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
        SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
            ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, strings, new SheetContentsHandler() {

            @Override
                public void startRow(int rowNum) {
                }
                @Override
                public void endRow() {
                }
                @Override
                public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue) {
                }
                @Override
                public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName) {

                }

            }, 
            false//means result instead of formula
            );
            sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
            sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SAX parser appears to be broken - " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks O.C exactly what I was looking for processing over 250k rows. Perfectly works.

Comment: Many thanks for the code snippet up there. Apache POI should post in their documentation an example as the one above to advertise those APIs more readily.

Comment: @O.C Thanks a ton!! Could you please tell how to consider blank cells in excel using the above code?

Comment: Is there a way using an iterator-based / row-based approach? I would like to wrap an iterator around it with hasNext() and next() methods so that the caller has more influence. In this event-based approach I have no control over the progress, because I have to fetch all events until no events are there.

Comment: but this is an xlsx parser not xls parser :(

Comment: This is where I copy-pasted from!

Comment: Where is the content of the xlsx?

Comment: @Anand still around?

Answer (score 2):

In the bellwo example I'll add a complete code how to parse a complete excel file (for me 60Mo) into list of object without any problem of "**out of memory**" and work fine:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class DistinctByProperty {

    private static OPCPackage xlsxPackage = null;
    private static PrintStream output= System.out;
    private static List<MassUpdateMonitoringRow> resultMapping = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\aberguig032018\\Downloads\\your_excel.xlsx");

        double bytes = file.length();
        double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
        double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
        System.out.println("Size "+megabytes);

        parseExcel(file);
    }

    public static void parseExcel(File file) throws IOException {

        try {
            xlsxPackage = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutePath(), PackageAccess.READ);
            ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(xlsxPackage);
            XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(xlsxPackage);
            StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
            XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
            int index = 0;
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                try (InputStream stream = iter.next()) {
                    String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
                    output.println();
                    output.println(sheetName + " [index=" + index + "]:");
                    processSheet(styles, strings, new MappingFromXml(resultMapping), stream);
                }
                ++index;
            }

        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OpenXML4JException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processSheet(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, MappingFromXml mappingFromXml, InputStream sheetInputStream) throws IOException, SAXException {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
        try {
            XMLReader sheetParser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
            ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(
                    styles, null, strings, mappingFromXml, formatter, false);

            sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
            sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
            System.out.println("Size of Array "+resultMapping.size());
        } catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SAX parser appears to be broken - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

you have to add a calss that implements

> SheetContentsHandler

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MappingFromXml implements SheetContentsHandler {

    private List<myObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
    private myObject myObject = null;
    private int lineNumber = 0;
    /**
     * Number of columns to read starting with leftmost
     */
    private int minColumns = 25;
    /**
     * Destination for data
     */
    private PrintStream output = System.out;

    public MappingFromXml(List<myObject> list) {
        this.result = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void startRow(int i) {
        output.println("iii " + i);
        lineNumber = i;
        myObject = new myObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void endRow(int i) {
        output.println("jjj " + i);
        result.add(myObject);
        myObject = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
        int columnIndex = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();

        if(lineNumber > 0){
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: {//Tech id
                    if (formattedValue != null && !formattedValue.isEmpty())
                        myObject.setId(Integer.parseInt(formattedValue));
                }
                break;
                //TODO add other cell
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void headerFooter(String s, boolean b, String s1) {

    }
}
```

For more information visite this [link](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Answer (score -1):

I too faced the same issue of OOM while parsing xlsx file...after two days of struggle, I finally found out the below code that was really perfect;

This code is based on sjxlsx. It reads the xlsx and stores in a HSSF sheet.

```
           [code=java] 
            // read the xlsx file
       SimpleXLSXWorkbook = new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(new File("C:/test.xlsx"));

        HSSFWorkbook hsfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet hsfSheet = hsfWorkbook.createSheet();

        Sheet sheetToRead = workbook.getSheet(0, false);

        SheetRowReader reader = sheetToRead.newReader();
        Cell[] row;
        int rowPos = 0;
        while ((row = reader.readRow()) != null) {
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row hfsRow = hsfSheet.createRow(rowPos);
            int cellPos = 0;
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if(cell != null){
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell hfsCell = hfsRow.createCell(cellPos);
                    hfsCell.setCellType(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    hfsCell.setCellValue(cell.getValue());
                }
                cellPos++;
            }
            rowPos++;
        }
        return hsfSheet;[/code]
```

Comment: This example shows how to write to an excel file, the question is about how do we write to an excel file in poi.