# Apache POI SAX Parsing - How to get actual value of the cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I had a requirement to parser very large excel files using apache poi with limit memory. After googling, I came to know that poi provides SAX parser to parser large file effectively without consuming lot of memory.

[Apache POI SAX Parser example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java)

```
  private class SheetToCSV implements SheetContentsHandler {
    private boolean firstCellOfRow = false;
    private int currentRow = -1;
    private int currentCol = -1;

    private void outputMissingRows(int number) {
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<minColumns; j++) {
                output.append(',');
            }
            output.append('\n');
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startRow(int rowNum) {
        // If there were gaps, output the missing rows
        outputMissingRows(rowNum-currentRow-1);
        // Prepare for this row
        firstCellOfRow = true;
        currentRow = rowNum;
        currentCol = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void endRow(int rowNum) {
        // Ensure the minimum number of columns
        for (int i=currentCol; i<minColumns; i++) {
            output.append(',');
        }
        output.append('\n');
    }

    @Override
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
            XSSFComment comment) {
        if (firstCellOfRow) {
            firstCellOfRow = false;
        } else {
            output.append(',');
        }

        // gracefully handle missing CellRef here in a similar way as XSSFCell does
        if(cellReference == null) {
            cellReference = new CellAddress(currentRow, currentCol).formatAsString();
        }

        // Did we miss any cells?
        int thisCol = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();
        int missedCols = thisCol - currentCol - 1;
        for (int i=0; i<missedCols; i++) {
            output.append(',');
        }
        currentCol = thisCol;

        // Number or string?
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(formattedValue);
            output.append(formattedValue);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            output.append('"');
            output.append(formattedValue);
            output.append('"');
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName) {
        // Skip, no headers or footers in CSV
    }
}
```

In the example provided in the above link, the method 'cell' has access only to formatted value however I need to access the actual value of the cell.

Comment: Write your own SAX handler to pass in?

Comment: you can see my complete example in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020658/error-while-reading-large-excel-files-xlsx-via-apache-poi/51818500#51818500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation of the streaming interface does not provide this. So in order to achieve this you will need to copy the code of the underlying  [XSSFSheetXMLHandler](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFSheetXMLHandler.java) and adjust it so that the cell-content is not formatted.

Comment: Thanks a lot @centic