# Get each cells data from Excel converted to XML to stored to DB

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, xssf

After looking for some resources, I could load an Excel file which contain 1.000.000 rows data. But, I did not know how to get each data. Here is my code so far...

```
public void create(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    try {
        InputStream fileStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
        OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(fileStream);
        XSSFReader xssf = new XSSFReader(opc);
        SharedStringsTable sst = xssf.getSharedStringsTable();
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator itr = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator)xssf.getSheetData();

// I just realize, if I running below for-loop,
// this only print strings and in random order, not in the same order as the excel file.
// 20 is just an example

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(sst.getEntryAt(i).getT().toString());
        }

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            InputStream is = itr.next();
            if (itr.getSheetName().equals("MY_SHEET_NAME")) {
                while ("data is avaiable, this is just example, I'll use something like hasNext() for the row in the sheet, but I dont know how to do it" != null) {
                    // Want to process and get all data in each cells, then store to DB
                    // What I did not know, is how to get data in each cells
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Sheet not found");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error is: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }

        if (opc != null){
            opc.close();
        }

        if (fileStream != null) {
            fileStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020658/error-while-reading-large-excel-files-xlsx-via-apache-poi) to process the sheet, but I did not get how to grab the data in each cells. Any help will really help me..

**Update**

if I read the doc of apache POI, [here](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29), from the link, code part that will process my excel is here:

```
public void processOneSheet(String filename) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        XMLReader parser = fetchSheetParser(sst);

        // To look up the Sheet Name / Sheet Order / rID,
        //  you need to process the core Workbook stream.
        // Normally it's of the form rId# or rSheet#
        InputStream sheet2 = r.getSheet("rId2");
        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheet2);
        parser.parse(sheetSource);
        sheet2.close();
    }
```

But, after call `parser.parse(sheetSource)`, how I could get each data from each row and column? Because I wanna do validation on each data on each cells, then store it to database.

**Update 2**
I've try using this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818500/10454516. I could get the data, I've try to insert myObjectRepo.save(result) or myObjectRepo.save(myObject), both I placed the code inside void endRow method and I also try to place it right after switch but inside the if(lineNumber > 0), but its always return NullPointerException. But if I did not call save method, I try to print the result in the console, the result is printed.

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings-sample has a runnable version of POI's XLSX2CSV sample that uses the streamed data to generate CSV.

Comment: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader also streams the xlsx input but its probably easier to use then the SAX parser approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd like to answer my own question. After several experiments/trials and also based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818500/10454516), I've made it to upload excel file which has at least 1.000.000 rows data and stored into db (postgresql). For upload, read and insert 1.000.000 rows data needs 5 minutes. Here is the link to the [project](https://github.com/ahmdichsan/Excel-Uploader). Hope this could help anybody who need it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way you could grab the excel data is :

```
try {
        InputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(mFileName); 
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        int col = 0, colPR = 1;
        int pageRank = 0;
        String url = null;

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            url = row.getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mFileName);
        wb.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've tried using XSSFWorkbook, but it's memory consuming. Because my excel file will contain approx 700k rows data. So thats why I did not use XSSFWorkbook and use that my current approach