# NullPointerException even all of the object initialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to do exactly what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818500/10454516) code doing. I already got the data. But when I try to call `repo.save()` as below, its always `NullPointerException`. When I try to add anotation `@Service` at the top of the class, it shows error that the bean not created. Do Autowired need `@Service`? If it is yes, then I have to create the bean in a class with `@Configuration` anotation, isn't it?

```
public class MappingFromXml implements SheetContentsHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectRepository repo;

    private List<MyObject> result = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    private MyObject myObjectVar = new MyObject();
    private int lineNumber = 0;
    /**
     * Number of columns to read starting with leftmost
     */
    private int minColumns = 25;
    /**
     * Destination for data
     */

    public MappingFromXml(List<MyObject> list) {
        this.result = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void startRow(int i) {
        lineNumber = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void endRow(int i) {]
        result.add(myObject);
        if (i > 0) {
            result.add(myObjectVar);
            if (i == 2) {
                // 2 because my data only contain 2 rows
                try {
                    System.out.println(result);
                    // the result printed in the console

                    if (result != null) {
                        System.out.println("result not null");
                        // this is printed in the console
                        if (repo == null) {
                            System.out.println("repo is null");
                            // this is printed in the console
                            repo.save(result);
                            // then, throw error NullPointerExceptions on this line
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // I provide the printed stacktrace below
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
        int columnIndex = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();

        if(lineNumber > 0){
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: {//Name
                    if (formattedValue != null && !formattedValue.isEmpty())
                        myObject.setName(formattedValue);
                }
                break;
                //TODO add other cell
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void headerFooter(String s, boolean b, String s1) {

    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is the log error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.app.service.MappingFromXml.endRow(MappingFromXml.java:69)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.endElement(XSSFSheetXMLHandler.java:389)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.app.service.DataDetailServiceImpl.processSheet(DataDetailServiceImpl.java:95)
    at com.app.service.DataDetailServiceImpl.create(DataDetailServiceImpl.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.service.DataServiceImpl.create(DataServiceImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.api.DataAPI.create(DataAPI.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: `if (repo == null) {repo.save(result);}` you see the problem?

Comment: Is the Repository extending CrudRepository 

example : MyObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Class,Integer> ?

And if (repo == null) then IsNULL !

Comment: In which line you get the NPE? How do you initialize the class?

Comment: share the error log

Comment: @Guy I want to show that the repo is null, then its executed. If I wrote repo != null, then repo.save never called

Comment: @Akza well you don't initialize it anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @SanRyu the Repo already extends JpaRepository and already use Repository anotation but still NPE. As I said to Guy, I want to show that the repo is null. Not the result. Even if I change into repo != null, then the repo.save never called

Comment: @Guy then how to initialized it? Is using Autowired not enough? or do I have to use MyObjectRepository repo = new MyObjectRepository()? I never use it before.. And AFAIK, Autowired could solve the repo.save method without have to initialize a new object

Comment: @Jens when the repo.save(result) executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (result != null) {
    System.out.println("result not null");
    if (repo == null)
        System.out.println("repo is null");
    else 
        repo.save(result);
}
```

UPDATE:

Do you have the @Component annotation on the implementation of the Repository ?

```
@Component
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository { }
```

Is the Repository interface extends maybe CrudRepository ?

```
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Class, Integer> { }
```

Finally if everything checks out... Try to create a constructor using @Autowire

```
private Repository repo;

@Autowired
public Class(Repository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

And see if the repo in the constructor initializes.

UPDATE 2:

Is the repository in the "same place as the other repositories" ?
Maybe you put it in another package and you forgot to let the Spring know that you use some Repos from another location.

```
@ComponentScan({ "org.somepackage.repos", "org.somepackage.anotherrepoplace" })
```

This annotation is located in the class Application, where the Main is.

Comment: its throw error, NPEs...

Comment: @Hulk did you know what is the root cause?

Comment: @Akza there are multiple ways to make this work - which one is best for your case depends on how you want to use this. They are explained in detail in the question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @SanRyu big thanks!!!! Using constructor solve my problem. Actually, I also passed a repo variable from a class with Service anotation. Because at that Service class, I call the XML class, so I pass the repo from the Service class to the XML class. Then, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I always use constructor @Autowired, because it fixes many of this problems, and because I make tests, using mocks and I don't always want to inject everything. Maybe I inject null in one of the ctor parameters.
Good luck.