# Out of memory when opening a spreadsheet with Apache POI

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-poi

i am trying to read an excel that is of 50Mb in size and containg various sheets in it through poi in java but the issue is that when i try to creat the object i got the exception of which the stack trace I have posted below.
for out of memory space error i have configured this

```
-Xmx1024m -Duser.timezone=GMT0 already
```

below is the snapshot in which i am trying to read the excel fist and then convrting it into byte array later on passing it as bytr stream where i detect it extension and it is of .xlsx type so the momnet i try to creat the object i got the below exception please advise how to overcome from this

```
     String fileName = "C:\\abc\\xret.xlsx";


FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
             ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) fileName.length()];
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
                processExcelObjects( bytes);
```

later on below i am creating the objects further as shown below

```
        byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        if (byteArrayInputStream.available() != -1 )
                { 
                  if (filename.lastIndexOf("."))).equalsIgnoreCase(".xlsx") )
                      {

                     XSSFWorkbook workbookXlsx = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
                       //**** got the exception ********//                       
                     workbookXlsx = new  XSSFWorkbook(byteArrayInputStream); //  ******  on this line I got the exception *********//

                 }
```

the exception that i got while creating the above workbookXlsx object is

```
                 org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
            Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
            at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3039)
            at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3060)
            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

please advise is it poi internal exception or heap space one

Comment: May not be an answer but definitely a good place to start [OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap?rq=1)

Comment: You ran out of memory.

Comment: i am running this with this parameter -Xmx1024m -Duser.timezone=GMT0 already

Comment: please advis how to overcome from this error

Comment: Processing large xlsx file in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897766/processing-large-xlsx-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

It's **not** a POI internal exception, you did run out of memory.

You can try to increase to `-Xmx2048m` or more, but consider a different approach, like the one suggested by @sibnick in the comments:

[Processing large xlsx file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897766/processing-large-xlsx-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that your java does not have enough memory to allocate in order to run this.

can use java -Xms -Xmx on the command line.

If you run the application using Eclipse ,

Right click on project -> Run As -> Run Configurations..-> Select Arguments tab -> In VM Arguments you can increase your JVM memory allocation

refer this documentation for learn more about vmoptions
[oracle - vmoptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some memory allocation problem you should use

```
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(bFile)) != -1;) {
                        bos.write(bFile, 0, readNum); 
}
```

replace buf variable to bFile variable and check it.