# Java Heap Error in Talend

Tags: java, out-of-memory, talend

I am trying to read a 30-60 MB of excel file in talend, but it is giving following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$ScrubBuffer.<init>(Locale.java:1804)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getScrubBuffer(Locale.java:1904)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.getValueAsString(Xobj.java:1205)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.fetch_text(Xobj.java:1796)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.get_wscanon_text(XmlObjectBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_dated(XmlObjectBase.java:1269)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaLongHolder.longValue(JavaLongHolder.java:53)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.getLongValue(XmlObjectBase.java:1502)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTRowImpl.getR(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getRowNum(XSSFRow.java:322)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initRows(XSSFSheet.java:229)
[statistics] disconnected
[statistics] disconnected
[statistics] disconnected
[statistics] disconnected
[statistics] disconnected
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:193)
at    org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:180)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:221)
at de.cimt.talendcomp.tfileexcelpoi.SpreadsheetFile.initializeWorkbook(SpreadsheetFile.java:281)
at cdif_validation.validation_partsourcingtab3_0_1.Validation_PartSourcingTab3.tFileExcelWorkbookOpen_1Process(Validation_PartSourcingTab3.java:774)
at cdif_validation.validation_partsourcingtab3_0_1.Validation_PartSourcingTab3.tFileList_1Process(Validation_PartSourcingTab3.java:696)
at cdif_validation.validation_partsourcingtab3_0_1.Validation_PartSourcingTab3.runJobInTOS(Validation_PartSourcingTab3.java:8268)
at cdif_validation.validation_partsourcingtab3_0_1.Validation_PartSourcingTab3.runJob(Validation_PartSourcingTab3.java:8110)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.tRunJob_3Process(CDIF_Validation.java:1175)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.tForeach_1Process(CDIF_Validation.java:983)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.tFileList_1Process(CDIF_Validation.java:820)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.tJava_1Process(CDIF_Validation.java:634)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.tPrejob_1Process(CDIF_Validation.java:529)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.runJobInTOS(CDIF_Validation.java:1885)
at cdif_validation.cdif_validation_0_1.CDIF_Validation.main(CDIF_Validation.java:1722)
```

I have tried increasing xms upto 1 GB and xmx size upto 6 GB. also I tried using disk to store temp data.
How to resolve this problem??

Comment: At first glance, having 1GB of heap space might appear to be totally sufficient for a 60MB Excel file.  However, I suspect that the in memory size of an Excel file could be substantially larger than its size on disk.

Comment: Consider reviewing your code, looks like you have some kind of memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem with Apache POI. Its because POI has large memory footprint. Now you can try to do some work-aroud  like process your file by smaller parts or try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897766/processing-large-xlsx-file-in-java) and do some "optimization".

Also look Apache POI [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109) to point 14. to get some recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

The default talend components use way more memory than required. 
I believe it is because that 60MB xlsx file is **entirely** uncompressed in memory. Even if you're just reading 1 row from 1 tab.

To overcome on this limitation you can try to add more and more memory or look for a different way. I usually use the tFileExcel components from Jan Lolling.
You can obtain these from the [talend marketplace](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplacesearch:gallery=marketplace%252F1&ob=releaseDate&o=0&c=20&d=true&s=tFileExcel&f=&tf=Talend%2520Studio%2520Add-ons&bf=&cat=&title=Search%2520Results).