# How to solve the java heap space error while loading the large xls file using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, large-files

I am trying to load and parse a xls file which is of 11mb and I am using WorkbookFactory.create(myFile)) to load it.But I am not able to load this file  and parse it.Can anyone help me out of this this the code I am using in my program ,

```
public class LargeExcelManager {

    private Workbook wb ;

    public Workbook getWb() {
        return wb;
    }

    public void setWb(Workbook wb) {
        this.wb = wb;
    }

    public LargeExcelManager(String fileName)throws Exception {

        openWorkbook(fileName);
    }

    private void openWorkbook(String fileName)throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("Can be added now");
            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            this.setWb(WorkbookFactory.create(myFile)); // Here i am trying to set the large file 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to get some information out of it ,

```
@Override
public List<String> start() {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Activity number " + activityId + " started");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workbook wb  = excelManager.getWb();

    for (int i=0; i<wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        if(wb.getSheetName(i).contains("Loan information")) {
            //sheetNames.add( wb.getSheetName(i) );
            result.addAll(processSheet(wb.getSheetAt(i)));
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Activity number " + activityId + " completed");
    return result;
}
```

But it is failing me every time I am trying to load it. Can anyone help me somehow?

I am getting this error using POI 3.16

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3044)
```

Comment: this.setWb(WorkbookFactory.create(myFile));  not helping me to achieve my goal

Comment: How is it failing? Do you get an exception? Which version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: It is failing just after the line Can be added now
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3044)

Comment: i am using POI 3.16

Comment: @rjdkolb can you help ?

Comment: @rjdkolb i have tried every possible ways to load the file but getting exception of heap space

Comment: What value are you using for `-Xmx`?