# Reading large size excel using apache poi

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I am facing an issue when trying to open and read an xlsx file size of around 100MB, 650k rows and about a total of 10,400,000 cells count.

This is the issue i get:

```
org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Tried to read data but the maximum length for this record type is 100,000,000.
If the file is not corrupt and not large, please open an issue on bugzilla to request 
increasing the maximum allowable size for this record type.
You can set a higher override value with IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride()
```

It hit error on this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

I tried using InputStream instead of FileInputStream, same issue. And if i add

```
IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride(1000000000);
```

I get the java heap space error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

My eclipse.ini settings already at max 2GB heap space (-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m). Are there anything that i can do to read more than the maximum length ?

Comment: Try run parameter -Xmx?g, where ? = number of gigabytes of maximum heap size.

Comment: @szeak my eclipse.ini is alreayd at max limit. -Xms256m
-Xmx2048m

Comment: I was thinking put this in `Run->Run...->VM arguments` section.

Comment: It is more memory friendly, when you thinking in other way of processing the data. e.g. convert it to CSV, than read and process the csv line-by-line.

Comment: @szeak i added the arguments, still facing the same issue. i added -Xms256m
-Xmx8g

Comment: @szeak dont think i can convert to CSV, because i need to open the excel first, which i having issue on that line

Comment: We have a good answer here: [Processing large xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897766/processing-large-xlsx-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Processing large xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897766/processing-large-xlsx-file)

Comment: Note: The settings in the eclipse.ini are just for Eclipse itself, they are nothing to do with programs you run from Eclipse - those are set in the Run Configuration.